# Do While Loop, update name of maximum donor

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a program that needs to stop when the target of £500 has been met. I have to use a DO WHILE loop to do this.

It needs to record how many donations it receives before it reaches £500, also it needs to record the name of the person with the highest donation given and what the largest donation was.

I cannot get the program to update the name of the person with the highest donation. The code I have so far is below. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

I have a red line coming up under 'namemax' when I try to call it at the end outside of the loop, saying 'not initialized'

```
    enter codeimport java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 11/02/2015
 * Time: 15:45
 * UPDATE COMMENT ABOUT PROGRAM HERE
 */
public class DoWhile
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
      final double TOTAL=500;
      String name,namemax;
      double donation, donationTotal=0,currentMax=0;
      int howManyDonation=0;

      do
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter your name below");
         name = keyboard.next();
         System.out.println("");


         System.out.println("Please enter the amount you would like to donate below");
         donation = keyboard.nextDouble();


         howManyDonation++;

         donationTotal = donationTotal+donation;


         if(donation>currentMax)
         {

            currentMax=donation;
            namemax=name;

         }//if


      }//doWhile
      while(donationTotal!=TOTAL);

      System.out.println("The total number of donations is " + howManyDonation);
      System.out.println("The largest donation was " + currentMax);
      System.out.println("The name of the person with the largest donation is " + namemax);





   }//main
}//class
 here
```

Comment: namemax variable not initialized check http://ideone.com/iF1lZ9

Comment: Accept one of the answers if you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line

```
String name,namemax;
```

into this:

```
String name,namemax = null;
```

Furthermore, change this

```
  while(donationTotal != TOTAL);
```

into this:

```
  while(donationTotal < TOTAL);
```

Comment: Look at the while condition too!

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty simple problem here. You are updating namemax inside of an if loop only. That means that as far as the code is concerned, there is a possible situation in which it could never be assigned. In practice, because of what you are doing, that can't actually happen but the compiler doesn't understand that.

To fix it,

change

```
string name,namemax;
```

to

```
string name;
string namemax = "";
```

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

it gives at least one sutuation where `namemax` not will be set. So you have to initialize the string.

Simply change

```
  String name,namemax ;
```

To

```
  String name,namemax = null;
```

or

```
 String name,namemax = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't guarantee that you'll actually set the `namemax` before you exit the loop. You should initialize `namemax` to the empty string to fix this problem.